# Pubsubhubbub on Rails. How to extract the raw POST body contents from the POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websub, subscribe

I am having trouble setting up a pubsub enabled subscriber app using rails. I have currently subscribed to the open hub pubsubhubbub.appspot.com and am receiving pings to my application's endpoint. (as of now i have created a counter which increments everytime the end point is pinged). But i am not able to understand as to how to extract the raw POST body contents from the POST. I am new to pubsub and am eager to experiment with it. I came across this blog post but it is not language specific.

---

Source: Joseph Smarr: Implementing PubSubHubbub subscriber support: A step-by-step guide. http://josephsmarr.com/2010/03/01/implementing-pubsubhubbub-subscriber-support-a-step-by-step-guide/

> Now you’re ready for the
>   pay-out–magically receiving pings from
>   the ether every time the blog you’ve
>   subscribed to has new content! You’ll
>   receive inbound requests to your
>   specified callback URL without any
>   additional query parameters added
>   (i.e. you’ll know it’s a ping and not
>   a verification because there won’t be
>   any hub.mode parameter included).
>   Instead, the new entries of the
>   subscribed feed will be included
>   directly in the POST body of the
>   request, with a request Content-Type
>   of application/atom+xml for ATOM feeds
>   and application/rss+xml  for RSS
>   feeds. Depending on your programming
>   language of choice, you’ll need to
>   figure out how to extract the raw POST
>   body contents. For instance, in PHP
>   you would fopen the special filename
>   php://input  to read it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/raw_post

Comment: Is the answer what you are after?

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say but I'm assuming you are running Rails 3.x?

To get the raw POST body you simply use request.raw_post in your controller. This will give you a long string that looks like a request parameters string: some_var=something&something_else=something_else... which you can then parse to get at what you want.

However, look at you development logs for an incoming request and see if the params hash isn't a better option for you. The service should post the data under some variable name, such as some_var above, and the params hash will hold an params[:some_var] containing only that data. No need for you to dig it out on your own in other words.